# What is considered promotional content?

Tags: discussion, spam, moderators, account-suspension

I recently ran into a question with the [three.js] tag that asked for help with a 3D globe randomly disappearing. This question had a link to a working demo with the problem, and the code showing the relevant segment. Links to working demos are allowed, and [even encouraged in the how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself.

As far as I can tell [this question did exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70308463/sphere-just-disappears-from-my-three-js-scene). The link shows the 3D globe that disappears, effectively demonstrating the problem. However, the edit history (screenshot below) shows that the link was removed multiple times without explanation. The OP attempted to add it back, only for it to be removed again:

[image]

After the second removal of the link, the account was suspended for "promotional content".
[image]

My question is, what is considered "promotional content"? The link was hireabadass.com, which isn't a business or spam, it's literally just a demo of the 3D globe referenced in the original question. I understand it *could* sound like a recruiting service, but immediately after opening it's evident that's not the case. How can this account be suspended for 7 days for promotional content, when it was just following the "live example you can link to" suggestion?

Comment: You mentioned in a comment on the main post that you raised a custom flag. I assume the flag hasn't been handled yet?

Comment: I doubt that the user was banned because of this post. There is no indication that the link was meant as promotional content. Most likely they have spammed more across the site.

Comment: @Dharman How can we corroborate this? Looking at OP's history, this is the only infraction. And the suspension occurred immediately after the question was closed, suggesting this was the culprit.

Comment: There's no reliable way that regular users can check if the user had other infractions, and only the moderator who issued the suspension can answer with certainty why they chose to suspend the user (other mods may be able to make educated guesses, of course).

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/208273)

Comment: Also worth noting: this is [not the first time they've posted a low-quality question linking that site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70304534).

Comment: @RyanM *Technically* true, but it looks like those questions are the same. The first one was closed for lacking debugging details, the OP self-deleted, and then posted a new question with debugging details a few hours later. Yes, the user should have added in the details to the original question and tried to get it reopened, but it's not *really* multiple posts with the link, is it?

Comment: @cigien I have mixed feelings on that, largely because the UI gives misleading advice suggesting that people _should_ post a new question.  I don't think those posts, alone, are enough to make it promotional content, but I also don't think there's a reason to not edit out the link.

Comment: *"As far as I can tell this question did exactly that."*  They missed the last part: "*but also copy the code into the question itself.*"

Comment: @RyanM Sure, I'm not claiming that the link shouldn't have been removed, or anything like that. I'm just pointing out that adding the link, even a second time, doesn't seem to warrant a 1 week suspension. Of course, we don't really have the full information available to us, so I guess we should just wait for a moderator to respond, if they choose to do so.

Comment: @RyanM The code is not very well formatted, but it's there: `const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);` It would've been silly to copy the entire program, when only the suspected culprit would suffice.

Comment: @Marquizzo Generally, debugging questions should have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Would be easier if the user just write "This link demonstrates the problem I have:" before the link. It isn't really a good idea to (force mods to) follow random links on the Internet.

Comment: @Marquizzo "looking at OP's history" you won't be able to see deleted posts owned by the user; only moderators can see that information (as cigien mentioned already).

Comment: Promotional content is pretty easy to spot on stack exchange : it's typically prepended with either "The Overflow Blog" or "Collectives™®©".

Answer (score 59, accepted):

###### The question does not appear to be spam. I've removed the suspension.

Thank you for bringing this situation to my attention. I'm the moderator who issued the suspension. In retrospect, I was too hasty in classifying the user's recent posts as spam. I've removed the suspension and apologized directly to them in a moderator message.

In this case, I didn't go to the link. I saw a domain name which looked a **lot** like the typical "hire someone through us" spam domains we routinely see. The user had two questions, [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70304534/3773011), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70308463/3773011), both primarily containing the link, which were posted within several hours of each other with both questions being at the quality level we typically see for that type of spam. The content of the posts didn't directly address the reason for the site being linked, although it is implied (which we also see in a lot of spam). So, those posts looked an *awful lot* like spam. At the time, I didn't have a sandboxed, VPN'ed system available in order to test a probable spam link, so I didn't actually visit the link. I should have, however, considered that it might be a user engaging in another type of behavior which isn't permitted (deleting and reposting a question).

As to [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70308463/3773011), it appears to be a repost of the user's initial question on the subject, which they deleted after it was downvoted and correctly closed. Users are not permitted to avoid moderation actions by deleting and reposting the same question. Doing that is something for which we have a different stock moderator message, which would have been the more appropriate message to send in this case.

###### Users have the ability to respond to moderator messages/suspensions. Explaining a mistaken situation is one of the a major reasons that ability exists.

If the user felt the suspension was incorrect, then they could have and should have responded to the moderator message that goes along with any suspension. In their response they should have rationally explained that they felt the situation wasn't as described in the moderator message and that they request the suspension be reevaluated. If they had done so, I would have been notified with an inbox entry, which I would have read and investigated further. That does not, however, absolve me from the responsibility to have better evaluated the situation. It's just a way that was available for the user to quickly resolve any confusion.

###### Raising a custom flag, as you did, was the right way for you to bring the situation to moderator attention.

I did not handle your flag, so I can't tell you why the situation wasn't resolved when your flag was processed. Your flag does, however, appear sufficiently detailed. I have not yet conferred with the moderator who handled your flag.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be qualified as "not spam", the link seems to be tacked on without any context, and it could potentially be a spam seed (shows 'good' content now, but this could change).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It sounds like you're [engaging in pre-crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-crime). If the content is good now, how can you accuse someone of making it spam in the future? If the link turns to spam at a later date, you flag it and address it *then*, not before.

Comment: @Marquizzo The way the post is phrased, with the link included out of the blue, without any context, with a spammy name, yes I do. Moderators take similar approaches with what they call spam seeds.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Rather than marking it spam for the future potential to be spam, I would suggest archiving the page and using a link to that. this also preserves the state of the page at the time the question was asked.

Comment: A tangential discussion about moderators, moderator responsibilities, mistakes, and apologies, with vague allusions to "unfriendliness" has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240223/discussion-on-answer-by-makyen-what-is-considered-promotional-content).

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, promotional content would be something...

- ...that links to an external resource that is only tangentially related to the question or answer at hand...
- ...makes no disclosure of the poster's affiliation, and...
- ...is repeated for no practical reason other than to boost its awareness.

A diamond mod could come along and refine these a bit later on, but that's the gist.

A better way to frame the discussion would be to ask, "What is the point of this person putting a link in the question that goes somewhere?"  We explicitly like to discourage code on external sites as much as possible - even the archaic recommendation for fiddles is frowned upon, since if the fiddle goes down and Stack Overflow remains up, you don't really have your example code anymore to ask a question or share your answer with.

A relevant takeaway is that we still expect code as a part of the question, even *if* you link externally.

> If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself.** Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS.

Comment: By those criteria, that link was not promotional content. It is essential to demonstrate the problem at hand.

Comment: @Marquizzo Content that is essential to demonstrate the problem should be in the question itself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're right, but _that still doesn't make this spam_.

Comment: @Marquizzo:  I tend not to click links in questions these days so I'll take your word for it